# What are the reaction mechanisms for singlet oxygen in the atmosphere?

Tags: atmosphere, atmospheric-chemistry, upper-atmosphere, auroras

Just as the production cycles of Ozone are dependent on the incident falling ultraviolet light and is fairly complex, I was wondering what the process of the production of singlet oxygen in the atmosphere results in.

As Auroral light is produced, both ionized and excited state molecules, these chemical species are created in the atmosphere, yet I am unaware of what secondary products are made in this process.

Comment: triplet oxygen=ozone maybe read about it how ozone is made and how it breaks down.

Comment: I am talking about the excited state of molecular oxygen, O2, not O3. You are probably getting confused with Trioxygen, the official IUPAC name for Ozone.